# Angular SignalR opens several websockets

Tags: angular, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I have an Angular / ASP.net App where I recently implemented SignalR-Communication using WebSockets. The communication works so far, but from looking at the page's network connections I get the impression that sometimes several websocket connections are opened. It probably happens when the page reloads, but I don't know for sure.

[image]

each of these connections starts with ws:// and has a different sec-websocket-accept header, so these are all open connections right?

This is the function that gets called from the root component:

```
private setUpSignalR() {

if(SignalRService.isConnected)
  return;

this.signalRService.startConnection();
this.signalRService.addPushNotificationListener(); 
}
```

And inside the SignalRService-Class:

```
public startConnection = () => {

const protocol = window.location.protocol.replace('http://', 'ws://').replace('http://', 'ws://');
const host = window.location.host;

this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                        .withUrl(`${protocol}//${host}/apphub`,{
                          accessTokenFactory: () =>  this._settings.authorization?.access_token ,
                          skipNegotiation: true,
                          transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets
                        })                            
                        .build();
                  
this.hubConnection
  .start()
  .then(() => { 
    console.log('SinalR HubConnection started');
    SignalRService.isConnected = true;
  })      
  .catch(err => console.log('Error while starting connection: ' + err))


  this.hubConnection.onclose(() => {
    SignalRService.isConnected = false;        
    setTimeout(() => {        
      this.hubConnection.start().then(() => {            
        console.log("reconnected");
        SignalRService.isConnected = true;
      }).catch(err => console.log(err));
    }, 5000);
  });
```

I thought setting and reading the isConnected flag should be sufficient, but it still opens more connections. Any ideas how to ensure that this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 0):

While your hub is trying to connection your function setUpSignalR is likely being called multiple times, you should also create a variable called connecting that you set right away. Then in your if statement check if you're connecting or connected.